# Is it a good idea to store an encryption key as an environment variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, environment-variables

I am writing a command-line application in Python 3. The app will be run by different users on their local machines. Some parts of the application require to login to a database. I want to give the users the choice to store their credentials or type them in every time.

For storing the credentials (if the users chose so) I want to use a seperate file which is created on the local machine and which is encrypted. For the encryption of the file I need to generate a key.

Now my question: Is it a good idea to store that key needed for encryption and decryption as an environment variable (I want to distribute critical information and not just store them in another file with the app)? What solutions should I consider where to store the key? Are there different environment variables (in terms of safety)?

I am aware, that there is no perfect solution (especially not with a python script which is stored in plain text by itself), but I want to put some effort in thinking this through and not just use .netrc or something like this.

Thank you in advance for some ideas.

Frank

Answer (score 2):

### **Do not store any sensitive information in environment variables.**

Any other process with the user's permissions (in particular any other process running as the user) can view all the environment variables for all the processes the user runs. A process with admin (e.g. `root` or `sudo` access) can see all environment variables for all users.

That allows any rogue process to read all the environment variables for it's owning user, and any admin rogue process to read all environment variables generally.

In Linux, you can see these environment variables at:

```sh
cat /proc/<pid>/envoron
```

Where `<pid>` is the process ID of the process you want to "spy" on.

They're each separated by null characters, BTW.

Note that many shells like `bash` have internal variables that only become environment variables when you use the `export` function. Newer versions of `bash` are even clever enough that they only actually export them to the real environment when spawning children. However, they are exposed to other processes every time any child is spawned (even just a `grep` or a `cat`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My thinking was to distribute the critical information (credentials  in an encrypted file) and the decryption key in the environment variables so an attacker has to find both the file and the decrpytion key. Do you have a better solution for this problem?

Comment: If possible, store the credentials in either the user's keychain/GPG safe. If that's not practical or possible, then you're stuck with a file. If it's a Linux system, the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file has a private key that is already stored this way. SSH will only use the key if it and all the directories in it's `abspath` are owned by the user with only permissions for the user. As Serge says, it's a chicken-or-the-egg issue.

Comment: That RSA option can also be used to require a user-entered decryption passphrase to unlock the credentials, which might be applicable here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this kind of question boils down to a chicken and egg problem: the credentials should only be stored in encrypted form. And the decryption key should also be stored in encrypted form...

A common solution is to rely on the OS and file system permission: a file only readable by its owner can only be accessed by the owner... and anybody with admin privileges... But anyway you cannot expect to be protected from an admin. That is the rationale behind the good old `.netrc` or equivalent files.

Automatically reading a (only readable by owner) file into an environment variable is a close variation. If has the same security level and can be easier to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So should I use .netrc to store the decryption key in another file (e. g. in the home-directory of the user)? The chicken and egg problem is exactly the reason why I posted my question. I thought it could be a good idea to distribute the critical information to seperate locations.